# Remove white noise and blur from image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filter, signal-processing

I got and image A[nxm] blurred and i found the inverse filter H[kxl] to restore the original .If i add white noise to image

```
A = A + (0.0001)*randn(size(A));
```

and then try to restore it with same filter

```
original=fft2(A).*H;
```

Where H is in frequence domain
and then take ifft(original)

I got a full dark image. What's going on?How can i remove white noise?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you include your definition of H here?

Comment: Its allright.I found it.It was something with creating the initial signal